# Enable scrolling richtextbox while stdout is processed

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm calling an external command using the `ProcessCaller` class, and output it to `richtextbox`.
Since the command action does take some time (could be between 2 minutes and 3 hrs) and all this time there's an output to the `richtextbox`, I want the user to be able to scroll down/up, look at the log been created, check for errors, etc.
Currently, I cannot use the scroll bar until the command is finished.
Is it possible to allow the user to use the scroll bar while running an external command?

Comment: I don't know what the `ProcessCaller` class is, but you'll have to execute the command in a separate thread if you want the richtextbox to be responsive while it's executing.

Comment: Please provide some code. Using TextBox.Text += output; instead of TextBox.AppendText(output); should ensure that the text does not auto scroll. As previously stated, it should be executed on a separate thread - not the form messaging loop.

Comment: Do the job in separate thread. When you do your job without creating separate thread, your code runs in main thread: the thread that is responsible to interact with user and window messages. When you do such a long job, thread can't do it's job: handling window messages, showing updated text in your RichTextBox. So do it in separate thread, or call `Application.DoEvents()` frequently (which is not a good solution).